# Missing return information in Google Knowledge Graph API response

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-knowledge-graph

We used to get "detailedDescription" field in the result when querying "kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search" REST API for an id.

This is not the case anymore (regression from the recent days). I also tried using Google API explorer and their sample and it's not returning the field as well.

https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1/?apix_params=%7B%22ids%22%3A%5B%22%2Fm%2F0dl567%22%5D%7D

Can someone know when it'll be fixed?

Should we add extra info now in order to get this field as before?

Thanks in advance.

[According to Google example documatation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgPkV.jpg)
[No detailedDescription field in result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoUV3.jpg)